# How to locate a button inside an article tag using Selenium through Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I cannot detect a button inside an article of below code:

```
<article id="ride-f6ba24ca-d847-44b7-987e-81db6e6dee47" class="DetailPage__container--1VLdd"><div class="DetailPage__highlights--1uyrQ"><section></section><form aria-label="Offer highlights" class="DetailPage__section--qtXxV"><button type="submit"><span>Accept offer</span></button></form></div></article>
```

I try :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Details']"))
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[.//span[text()='Accept offer']]"))
```

with no luck

I cannot detect the element Accept offer with selenium in java

Comment: In a frame?  Loading dynamically (so you need to wait)?  Those are the usual culprits...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired element is an dynamic element so to locate the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *elementToBeClickable()* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("article[class^='DetailPage__container--'][id^='ride-']>div[class^='DetailPage__highlights--'] button[type='submit']>span")));
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//article[starts-with(@class, 'DetailPage__container--') and starts-with(@id, 'ride-')]/div[starts-with(@class, 'DetailPage__highlights--')]//button[@type='submit']/span[text()='Accept offer']")));
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer DebanjanB
I already try with WebDriverWait but with no luck but i try to get the element at once with findElement(By.xpath("//button[.//span[text()='Accept offer']]")).
Is this my fault?

Comment: anyway I try your solution and I will tell you soon

Comment: Your method throws a TimeException and it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Finally your method works with the below method

```
private void waitForElement(By by, long delay) {
    LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(delay);
    while (LocalDateTime.now().compareTo(end) <= 0) {
        if (driver.findElements(by).size() > 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

i run method wait first and then i check if ther is a list with elements like this below

```
if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//article[starts-with(@class, 'DetailPage__container--') and starts-with(@id, 'ride-')]/div[starts-with(@class, 'DetailPage__highlights--')]//button[@type='submit']/span[text()='Accept offer']")).size() > 0){//Here i call the element}
```

So if the element exists i can call it inside to if else there is no timeexception more